# How to color a row that is modified in datagrid and position on that row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I try:

```
    private int GetRowHandleByColumnValue(GridView view, string ColumnFieldName, object value)
    {

        int result = GridControl.InvalidRowHandle;
        for (int i = 0; i < view.RowCount; i++)
            if (Equals(value, view.GetRowCellValue(i, ColumnFieldName)))
                return i;
        return result;
    }

    private void Locate()
    {

        int rowHandle = GetRowHandleByColumnValue(dgvMedici, "Parafa", txtParafa.Text);
        if (rowHandle != GridControl.InvalidRowHandle)
        {
            dgvMedici.FocusedColumn = dgvMedici.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("Parafa");
            dgvMedici.FocusedRowHandle = rowHandle;
            dgvMedici.ShowEditor();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Not found!");
    }

    private void dgvMedici_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        if (view.FocusedRowHandle == e.RowHandle && !view.FocusedColumn.Equals(e.Column))
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }
```

it's possible to exist a function like Locate from Delphi in C#?

Comment: Not DataGridView. DevExpress.GridView maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can change colors and other row styles by using `DefaultCellStyle` property.

```
private void YourEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow(); // an example row
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange; // change back color to orange
    }
```